# How to make copies of the executable itself in C++?

Tags: c++, fstream

I want to make copies of an executable file itself multiple times.

I tried the following code:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::ifstream from("main.exe", std::ios::binary);
    auto buf { from.rdbuf() };

    for(int x { 0 }; x <= 10; ++x) {
        std::string name { "main" + std::to_string(x) + ".exe" };

        std::ofstream out(name, std::ios::binary);
        out << buf;
        out.close();
    }

    from.close();
    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't work as I expected (It does not copy the executable repeatedly. See the size column in the following screenshot):

[image: The executables not completely copied]

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but there's no need to call `out.close();` or `from.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: If I was treating symptoms (I don't have the energy at the moment to seriously analyze the code), I'd move the first two lines of `main` inside the loop.

Comment: The statement `out << buf;` will *extract* all data from `buf`, leaving nothing behind.

Comment: You never check that opening the file succeeds. Add `if(!from) { std::cout << std::strerror(errno) << '\n'; return 1; }` just after opening it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading from the input file stream buffer consumes the data. You need to reset the stream to the start after copying the file:

```
...

for (int x{ 0 }; x <= 10; ++x) {
    std::string name{ "main" + std::to_string(x) + ".exe" };

    std::ofstream out(name, std::ios::binary);
    out << buf;
    out.close();
    from.seekg(0, std::ios::beg); // need to go back to the start here
}

...
```

You could simply use the `std::filesystem` standard library functionality for this though:

```
int main() {
    std::filesystem::path input("main.exe");

    for (int x{ 0 }; x <= 10; ++x) {
        std::filesystem::path outfile("main" + std::to_string(x) + ".exe");

        std::filesystem::copy_file(input, outfile, std::filesystem::copy_options::overwrite_existing);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `seekg(0, ...)` will cause to read the file multiple times (once per save). Isn't it ?

Answer (score 2):

After you read all of the contents from the input buffer during your first iteration, your input buffer is empty. Thus, your subsequent iterations will also render empty copies. I suggest moving the `from` buffer initialization inside the loop like so:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    for (int x{ 0 }; x <= 10; ++x) {
        std::ifstream from("main.exe", std::ios::binary);
        auto buf{ from.rdbuf() };
        std::string name{ "main" + std::to_string(x) + ".exe" };

        std::ofstream out(name, std::ios::binary);
        out << buf;
        out.close();
        from.close();
    }

    
    return 0;
}
```

Here's what you should get:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the other answers the data will be read from the file multiple times (once per save).
This will happen if you create a new `std::ifstream` object inside the loop, and also happen if you use `seekg` to go to the beginning of the stream.

Since disk access is relatively slow (when compared to memory access), it will **more efficient** to read it **once into memory**, then **save** as many times as needed **from memory**.

The code below reads the file binary content into a `std::vector`. Then write the content of the vector multiple times to create the new files:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

int main() {

    // Read the entire main.exe file into memory:
    const std::string inFilename{ "main.exe" };
    std::ifstream inFile{ inFilename, std::ios_base::binary };
    std::vector<char> inFileData{ std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inFile), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() };
    inFile.close();

    // Save it as many times as needed:
    for (int x{ 0 }; x <= 10; ++x) 
    {
        std::string name{ "main" + std::to_string(x) + ".exe" };
        std::ofstream outFile{ name, std::ios::binary };
        outFile.write(inFileData.data(), inFileData.size());
        outFile.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first copy is done perfectly. My best guess is that the input buffer is empty afterwards, so all consecutive copies are empty.

Comment: This might be a reasonable comment; it's not an answer.